# How convert unicode to html entities like "&#1234;"?

Tags: php, utf8-decode

I have in mysql database unicode chars and i want to convert this to html entities? My site is in latin2 and its not possible to convert to UTF.  I tried to use a iconv or htmlentities but its not work properly.  Please give me some advice how to do that.

This string "♛ STUDENT NIGHT ♛ IMPREZA STUDENCKA ♛ STUDENCI WSTĘP " must be "`&#9819; STUDENT NIGHT &#9819; IMPREZA STUDENCKA &#9819; STUDENCI WST&#280;P` " after convert in php.

Comment: I don't see a difference?

Comment: Are the characters stored like "&#1234;" in the database? Also have you tried `html_entity_decode`?

Comment: No chars in database is in unicode.

Comment: @Epodax go to http://www.unicodetools.com/unicode/convert-to-html.php paste my first string and See result.  I need this result:-)

Comment: Any advice how to do that?

Comment: First you could try [`mb_convert_encoding`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php) to fix the encoding. Then you can do `htmlentities` to get html code.

Comment: @apokryfos something like that? mb_convert_encoding(htmlentities(♛ STUDENT NIGHT ♛ IMPREZA STUDENCKA ♛ STUDENCI WSTĘP))  ??

Comment: More like `htmlentities(mb_convert_encoding("wrongly encoded string", "UTF-8","ISO-8859-1"))`